# Agora.io React Native Broadcast Streaming: How to display the host's screen capture for non-host users?

Tags: react-native, agora.io, agora, agora-implementation

`Agora.io` React Native broadcast-streaming screen share

I am trying to implement agora Broadcast Streaming to my react native application, and follow [this](https://docs.agora.io/en/broadcast-streaming/get-started/get-started-sdk?platform=react-native) , and [this](https://docs.agora.io/en/broadcast-streaming/develop/product-workflow?platform=react-native).
It is just sending screen capture but as an audience role, I could not find a way to show screen capture of host.

```
{startScreenCaptureBool ? (
    <RtcSurfaceView
    style={styles.videoView}
    canvas={{
        uid: 0,
        sourceType: VideoSourceType.VideoSourceScreen,
        renderMode: RenderModeType.RenderModeFit,
    }}
    />
) : undefined}
```

This part is just showing local screen capture, but I want that, if user is not host, it shows hosts screen.
Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?